# SQLAlchemy Core convert select statement to update statement

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Now, I am using SQLAlchemy Core (NOT ORM) 1.4, and I've got two statements:

```py
stmt1 = sa.select(groups).where(groups.c.id == group_id)
stmt2 = sa.update(groups).where(groups.c.id == group_id)
```

I would like to know if there's a way to convert `stmt1` to `stmt2` dynamically because I want to build a statement like this:

```py
# doing something to convert stmt1 to stmt2. is it possible?
stmt2 = stmt2.values(**my_dict)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you build both statements dynamically? e.g. `args = [groups.c.id == group_id]` and `stm1 = sa.select(groups).where(*args)` and `stmt2 = sa.update(groups).where(*args)`

Comment: @jorzel I made a CRUD method, and I didn't want to pass (very similar format) two statements. I thought I may derive one from another. I posted an answer how I solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer by myself, so I post here.

At first, I asked if I can convert `select where` to `update where` using SQLAlchemy core.

It's possible using [Select().get_final_froms](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.get_final_froms), but it returns a tuple because we usually select or join with one or more tables.

My purpose was fetching one record which has to be updated.

Thus, I derived the select statement from update statement like this:

```py
stmt_update = sa.update(groups).where(groups.c.id == group_id)

stmt_select = sa.select(stmt_update.table).where(stmt_update.whereclause)
```

Now I don't have to pass very similar two statements. Thank you.